# AWS: SQS FIFO TPS limit per message group

Tags: amazon-web-services, limit, amazon-sqs, fifo

From the AWS SQS documentation for [FIFO queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) it says:

> FIFO queues also provide exactly-once processing but are limited to 300 transactions per second (TPS).

...

> FIFO queues support message groups that allow multiple ordered message groups within a single queue.

...

> Messages that belong to the same message group are always processed one by one, in a strict order relative to the message group (however, messages that belong to different message groups might be processed out of order).

Does any know if this means that the 300 TPS limit is applied to the while queue or per message group?

Answer (score 1):

The limit applies to the whole queue as can be seen from following extract in [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/)

> **Q: What is the throughput limit for an Amazon SQS FIFO queue?**
>
> A single FIFO queue currently supports throughput of up to 300
>   transactions per second (TPS). (A standard queue has unlimited
>   throughput.)